# nodejs - csvtojson not giving proper json keys in output

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

I am using `csvtojson` package in `nodejs`. I have written below code to convert my `csv` file but it is not converting into `json` properly. The keys in `json` do not have double brackets hence I am not able to get value using key.

```
var Converter = require("csvtojson").Converter;
var converter = new Converter({});

converter.fromFile("./file.csv", function(err,result){
    console.log(result);
});
```

Output shown is as below:

```
[ { a: 1, b: 2, c: 3 }, { a: 3, b: 4, c: 5 } ]
```

Hence it gives error as "`Key not found!! c`"

Can someone help.

The `csv` content is as below:

```
a,b,c
1,2,3
3,4,5
```

Comment: Can you post your CSV Content?

Comment: @DavidR Added csv content in the post

Comment: From the documentation, I was under the impression the output should be `[{"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}, {"a": 3, "b": 4, "c": 5}]`, and the problem would be taht it is a JSON string, and you need to call `JSON.parse` on it before retrieving keys. Another error could be in how you access `c`, but you didn't show the code for that.

Comment: I tried JSON.parse, it says
undefined:1
[object Object],[object Object]
 ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token o

Comment: You solution worked @DrakaSAN. Thanks. Please post solution, I will mark it as answer Thanks again!!

Comment: Done, but if the real error was that you tried to access `result.c` instead of `result[0].c`, please accept @Franck answer instead. Also, you talked about a error in the parsing, which make me doubt my comment was the real answer.

Comment: I used `JSON.stringify(result[i])` and its working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the documentation, it seems the output should be `[{"a": 1, "b": 2, "c": 3}, {"a": 3, "b": 4, "c": 5}]`, which is a JSON string.

To access the property of the objects, you would need to evaluate it with `JSON.parse`.

Another error could be in how you access `c`, but you didn't show the code for that.

Answer (score 0):

`console.log` doesn't give you json formatted output, it is the dump of the javascript object, formatting is different.

You need to address the results line by line. Your result is an array, each item being a line with all the fields. So you can address the first line's `c` key with :

```
result[0]['c']
```

Or you probably want to loop into this array to access each line :

```
converter.fromFile("./file.csv", function(err,result){
    for (var i in result) {
        var line=result[i];
        console.log("line "+i+":" + line.c);
    }
 });
```

Comment: I want to have a json response. I have json utility in place hence it will be easy to have a generic utility such that if i have json from csv then i can directly have values of key passed.

Comment: You want the json string from the javascript object ? Then use
     `console.log(JSON.stringify(result));`
In fact, this would work :
     `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(result));`

Comment: In addition, if you just want a plain csv to json converter you can use the command line tool provided with the module :
`./node_modules/.bin/csvtojson file.csv > file.json`.
And use `file.json` in a third party application.